# Telegram Inline Query - No Search Result

Tags: php, mysql, telegram, telegram-bot

I am working on an inline bot on telegram so as to respond with some commands.

I successfully made the bot and it shows the options I pre-entered in a mySQL database previously with the below code.

```
if (isset($update["inline_query"])) {
    $inlineQuery = $update["inline_query"];
    $queryId = $inlineQuery["id"];
    $queryText = $inlineQuery["query"];

    $filtered = array_filter($results_empty, function($v) { return (stripos($v['title'], $queryText) !== FALSE); });

    $postData2 = array(
        "inline_query_id" => $inlineQuery["id"], 
        "results" => json_encode($filtered), 
        "cache_time" => 0
    );

if (isset($queryText) && $queryText !== "") {

  apiRequestJson("answerInlineQuery", [
    "inline_query_id" => $queryId,
    "results" => $postData2["results"]
  ]);
} 
else {
      apiRequestJson("answerInlineQuery", [
        "inline_query_id" => $queryId,
        "results" => $postData["results"]
      ]);
     }
}
```

Yet, when $querytext is empty (`if (isset($queryText) && $queryText !== ""`), aka default when no texts has been input, the options from `$postData["results"]` all show up.

And when I typed in some queries (`if (isset($update["inline_query"]))`), nothing shows up from `$postData2["results"]`.
I confirm the `$filtered` from above actually works filtering thus `$postData2` is valid.

Can someone help with this issue?